# Find the length of the following parametric curve in R^3

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

$$\gamma(t)=(\log t\sqrt2,\frac{1}{3t},3t+1)$$
$$t\in [1/3,3]$$

my try :

*the tangent to the curve is :*
$$\gamma'(t)=\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{t},\frac{-1}{3t^2},3\right)$$

*the norm of the tangent to the curve:*
$$||\gamma(t)||=\left(\frac{2}{t^2}+\frac{1}{9t^4}+9\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

*expanding and simplifying :*
$$||\gamma(t)||=\frac{((12t^2+5)(12t^2+1))^\frac{1}{2}}{6t^2}$$

I don't know how to proceed to solve the integral from this

Comment: Check you simplifcation : it is wrong but the final result is very simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the curve is,
$$ \displaystyle ~\gamma(t)=(\sqrt2 \ln t,\frac{1}{3t},3t+1), t \in \left[1/3, 3\right]$$

Your work is correct till the step,

$ \displaystyle ||\gamma(t)|| = \sqrt{\frac{2}{t^2}+\frac{1}{9t^4}+9}$

But your simplification is incorrect.

$ \displaystyle ||\gamma(t)|| = \sqrt{\frac{2}{t^2}+\frac{1}{9t^4}+9} = \sqrt{\left(\frac 1 {3 t^2} + 3  \right)^2}$

So length of the curve is,

$ \displaystyle \int_{1/3}^3 \left(\frac 1 {3 t^2} + 3  \right) ~ dt$

which is a straightforward integral.